# Saving Collection to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC application and have written a class to load an XML file into a collection.

I now want to save that collection into the database, can someone advise of the best way to do this.

I am fairly new to development, so just finding my way around at the moment.

```
    public class MohitoXmlConfiguration
{
    public class Importer
    {
        private readonly string _xmlPath;

        public Importer(string pathToXmlFiles)
        {
            _xmlPath = pathToXmlFiles;
        }

        public IEnumerable<MohitoHoliday> ImportWsaHolidayUsingXElement()
        {
            var xmlFile = Path.Combine(_xmlPath, "WSAHoliday.xml");
            var stream = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            var holidayCollection = xdoc.Descendants("WSAHoliday");
            var MohitoCollection = new List<MohitoHoliday>();
            foreach (var element in holidayCollection)
            {
                var holiday = new MohitoHoliday
                {
                    Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    DisplayName = element.Attribute("DisplayName").Value
                };
                var dateNodes = element.Descendants("WSAHolidayDate");
                foreach (var dateNode in dateNodes)
                {
                    var startDate = dateNode.Attribute("StartDate").Value;
                    var startTime = dateNode.Attribute("StartTime").Value;
                    var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDate + " " + startTime);
                    var stopDate = dateNode.Attribute("EndDate").Value;
                    var stopTime = dateNode.Attribute("EndTime").Value;
                    var stopDateTime = DateTime.Parse(stopDate + " " + stopTime);
                    var holidayDates = new MohitoHolidayDates
                    {
                        StartDate = startDateTime,
                        EndDate = stopDateTime
                    };
                    holiday.Dates.Add(holidayDates);

                }
                MohitoCollection.Add(holiday);

            }

            return MohitoCollection;
        }
```

Comment: The best way to do... what? XML is data, why can you not use it directly? What is your “database”? Is it relational? What's its schema?

Comment: Hi to clarify.  I have written code to load the xml file which has data that I want to load into my database.  The code loads the file and iterates through the file to create the collection <List>.  What I am wondering now is do I iterate through the collection and save one record at a time or can I just throw the collection in one hit and have it create all the records.  Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most easy way interacting with a database is by using the Entity Framework ORM 
which you can use with the ASP.NET MVC.

Since you have already created the model it should be fairly easy. 
Try following the steps described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).